# Windows Small Business Server 2011 Standard - Certificate

Tags: windows-sbs-2011

Good morning.
I usually use Remote Desktop when I'm away and all was good until the renewal of the Certificate.
Now, when I try to connect from external to the server in Remote Desktop, the server reply that the Certificate is not valid.
When I open the certificate I read: The certificate is valid. Te Digital signature is invalid.
What I must to to solve the problem?
Thank you in advance

Comment: More details would be needed.

Comment: Hi, you can install the certificate in the remote machine to make it thrusted, as it seem a autogenerated’s one. For a fully thrusted one you need one generated by a third party

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell exactly what's going on based on the phrasing of your question.  It sounds like yagmoth555 is correct to me, for the most part.  Whatever machine you're using to remote desktop doesn't trust the authority that issued your certificate.

I'd also like to add that, well.  "connect from external to the server in Remote Desktop."

1. I hope you're using the official SBS VPN or some other VPN rather than accessing your server over the wilds of the internet.
2. It's possible that your remote machine doesn't trust the certificate authority that issued the certificate because it's not a member of the domain and you used the built in SBS certificate authority to issue the certificate.

My theory is that you used a commercial certificate when setting up the server and replaced it with an SBS-issued certificate, but that's just a guess.